# Eclipse Juno startup: EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005)

Tags: java, eclipse

So this is the thing I encounter when I try to lauch EclipsePortable.exe
The IDE worked perfectly yesterday. Rebooting has not helped, neither other SO solution (addding line below to eclipse.ini)

```
    -XX:CompileCommand=exclude,org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser.TypeConverter::*
```

Error File:

```
    #
    # A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
    #
    #  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x675d7417, pid=724, tid=1632
    #
    # JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_65-b17) (build 1.8.0_65-b17)
    # Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (25.65-b01 mixed mode windows-x86 )
    # Problematic frame:
    # V  [jvm.dll+0x37417]
    #
    # Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
    #
    # If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
    #   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
    #

    ---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

    Current thread (0x2602c000):  JavaThread "Start Level Event Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_in_vm, id=1632, stack(0x269f0000,0x26af0000)]

    siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0x26e95f83

    Registers:
    EAX=0xff110c4d, EBX=0x25f7f8f0, ECX=0x26e95f83, EDX=0x006f006e
    ESP=0x26aec594, EBP=0x26aec6c4, ESI=0x2602c000, EDI=0x25fa6bd0
    EIP=0x675d7417, EFLAGS=0x00010246

    Top of Stack: (sp=0x26aec594)
    0x26aec594:   2602c000 00000024 26aecb10 00000001
    0x26aec5a4:   00000000 26aec5c4 00000000 00000100
    0x26aec5b4:   00000100 00000000 00000000 00000000
    0x26aec5c4:   00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
    0x26aec5d4:   00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
    0x26aec5e4:   00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
    0x26aec5f4:   00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
    0x26aec604:   00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 

    Instructions: (pc=0x675d7417)
    0x675d73f7:   45 94 ff ff 00 00 83 f8 06 73 08 56 8b cf e8 26
    0x675d7407:   25 00 00 83 7e 04 00 0f 85 bf fe ff ff 8b 4f 08
    0x675d7417:   0f b7 11 89 55 c8 66 8b 45 c8 86 c4 83 47 08 02
    0x675d7427:   66 8b c8 8b 47 08 8b 00 89 45 c8 8b 45 c8 0f c8 


    Register to memory mapping:

    EAX=0xff110c4d is an unknown value
    EBX=0x25f7f8f0 is an unknown value
    ECX=0x26e95f83 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x260a2400
    EDX=0x006f006e is an unknown value
    ESP=0x26aec594 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x2602c000
    EBP=0x26aec6c4 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x2602c000
    ESI=0x2602c000 is a thread
    EDI=0x25fa6bd0 is an unknown value


    Stack: [0x269f0000,0x26af0000],  sp=0x26aec594,  free space=1009k
    Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
    V  [jvm.dll+0x37417]
    V  [jvm.dll+0x38218]
    V  [jvm.dll+0x39148]
    V  [jvm.dll+0x3ac26]
    V  [jvm.dll+0x4f87f]
    V  [jvm.dll+0x4ff5a]
    V  [jvm.dll+0x511a0]
    V  [jvm.dll+0x4dc1a]
    V  [jvm.dll+0x39219]
    V  [jvm.dll+0x3ac26]
    V  [jvm.dll+0x4f87f]
    V  [jvm.dll+0x4ff5a]
    V  [jvm.dll+0x511a0]
    V  [jvm.dll+0x4dc1a]
    V  [jvm.dll+0x39219]
    V  [jvm.dll+0x3ac26]
    V  [jvm.dll+0x4f87f]
    V  [jvm.dll+0x4ff5a]
    V  [jvm.dll+0x511a0]
    V  [jvm.dll+0x511ea]
    V  [jvm.dll+0xab3e8]
    V  [jvm.dll+0x7f9c2]
    V  [jvm.dll+0x7fba7]
    j  com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.<init>(Lcom/sun/org/apache/xerces/internal/util/SymbolTable;Lcom/sun/org/apache/xerces/internal/xni/grammars/XMLGrammarPool;Lcom/sun/org/apache/xerces/internal/xni/parser/XMLComponentManager;)V+781
    j  com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XIncludeAwareParserConfiguration.<init>(Lcom/sun/org/apache/xerces/internal/util/SymbolTable;Lcom/sun/org/apache/xerces/internal/xni/grammars/XMLGrammarPool;Lcom/sun/org/apache/xerces/internal/xni/parser/XMLComponentManager;)V+4
    j  com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XIncludeAwareParserConfiguration.<init>()V+4
    j  com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.SAXParser.<init>(Lcom/sun/org/apache/xerces/internal/util/SymbolTable;Lcom/sun/org/apache/xerces/internal/xni/grammars/XMLGrammarPool;)V+5
    j  com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.SAXParser.<init>()V+3
    j  com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.<init>(Lcom/sun/org/apache/xerces/internal/jaxp/SAXParserImpl;Lcom/sun/org/apache/xerces/internal/utils/XMLSecurityPropertyManager;Lcom/sun/org/apache/xerces/internal/utils/XMLSecurityManager;)V+1
    j  com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.<init>(Lcom/sun/org/apache/xerces/internal/jaxp/SAXParserFactoryImpl;Ljava/util/Map;Z)V+46
    j  com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl.newSAXParser()Ljavax/xml/parsers/SAXParser;+13
    j  org.eclipse.update.internal.configurator.ConfigurationParser.<init>()V+15
    j  org.eclipse.update.internal.configurator.PlatformConfiguration.loadConfig(Ljava/net/URL;Ljava/net/URL;)Lorg/eclipse/update/internal/configurator/Configuration;+21
    j  org.eclipse.update.internal.configurator.PlatformConfiguration.initializeCurrent(Lorg/eclipse/osgi/service/datalocation/Location;)V+32
    j  org.eclipse.update.internal.configurator.PlatformConfiguration.<init>(Lorg/eclipse/osgi/service/datalocation/Location;)V+27
    j  org.eclipse.update.internal.configurator.PlatformConfiguration.startup(Ljava/net/URL;Lorg/eclipse/osgi/service/datalocation/Location;)V+15
    j  org.eclipse.update.internal.configurator.ConfigurationActivator.getPlatformConfiguration(Ljava/net/URL;Lorg/eclipse/osgi/service/datalocation/Location;)Lorg/eclipse/update/internal/configurator/PlatformConfiguration;+2
    j  org.eclipse.update.internal.configurator.ConfigurationActivator.initialize()V+147
    j  org.eclipse.update.internal.configurator.ConfigurationActivator.start(Lorg/osgi/framework/BundleContext;)V+13
    j  org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run()Ljava/lang/Object;+64
    v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
    V  [jvm.dll+0x158985]
    V  [jvm.dll+0x21df3e]
    V  [jvm.dll+0x158a1e]
    V  [jvm.dll+0x10934f]
    C  [java.dll+0x1047]
```

[Skipped some lines, SO limits to 30000 characters]

```
    ---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

    Java Threads: ( => current thread )
      0x260a2400 JavaThread "[Timer] - Main Queue Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3424, stack(0x26df0000,0x26ef0000)]
      0x2609c000 JavaThread "Component Resolve Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3204, stack(0x26bf0000,0x26cf0000)]
      0x26019800 JavaThread "Framework Event Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3088, stack(0x26af0000,0x26bf0000)]
    =>0x2602c000 JavaThread "Start Level Event Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_in_vm, id=1632, stack(0x269f0000,0x26af0000)]
      0x2602a000 JavaThread "State Data Manager" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2644, stack(0x268f0000,0x269f0000)]
      0x25fd9000 JavaThread "Framework Active Thread" [_thread_blocked, id=2420, stack(0x267f0000,0x268f0000)]
      0x25296800 JavaThread "Service Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=116, stack(0x25ba0000,0x25ca0000)]
      0x25276800 JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3988, stack(0x25a60000,0x25b60000)]
      0x25275400 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3288, stack(0x25920000,0x25a20000)]
      0x25272800 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3100, stack(0x257e0000,0x258e0000)]
      0x25244000 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3180, stack(0x25620000,0x25720000)]
      0x2523ec00 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=940, stack(0x25520000,0x25620000)]
      0x029ac000 JavaThread "main" [_thread_blocked, id=2624, stack(0x00090000,0x00190000)]

    Other Threads:
      0x25238800 VMThread [stack: 0x25420000,0x25520000] [id=3076]
      0x252a1c00 WatcherThread [stack: 0x25ce0000,0x25de0000] [id=3808]

    VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

    VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

    Heap:
     def new generation   total 12288K, used 8243K [0x04c00000, 0x05950000, 0x0f6a0000)
      eden space 10944K,  63% used [0x04c00000, 0x052bccc8, 0x056b0000)
      from space 1344K, 100% used [0x056b0000, 0x05800000, 0x05800000)
      to   space 1344K,   0% used [0x05800000, 0x05800000, 0x05950000)
     tenured generation   total 27328K, used 3927K [0x0f6a0000, 0x11150000, 0x24c00000)
       the space 27328K,  14% used [0x0f6a0000, 0x0fa75df0, 0x0fa75e00, 0x11150000)
     Metaspace       used 6421K, capacity 6710K, committed 6784K, reserved 7552K

    Card table byte_map: [0x24c00000,0x24d10000] byte_map_base: 0x24bda000

    Polling page: 0x00280000

    CodeCache: size=32768Kb used=1350Kb max_used=1350Kb free=31418Kb
     bounds [0x02b30000, 0x02c88000, 0x04b30000]
     total_blobs=560 nmethods=389 adapters=102
     compilation: enabled

    Compilation events (10 events):
    Event: 3.369 Thread 0x25276800  386             org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.FilterImpl::compare (329 bytes)
    Event: 3.370 Thread 0x25276800 nmethod 386 0x02c7df88 code [0x02c7e300, 0x02c7f8f4]
    Event: 3.382 Thread 0x25276800  387             java.util.LinkedList$ListItr::checkForComodification (23 bytes)
    Event: 3.382 Thread 0x25276800 nmethod 387 0x02c807c8 code [0x02c808d0, 0x02c809dc]
    Event: 3.382 Thread 0x25276800  388             org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.BaseData::getStorageHook (53 bytes)
    Event: 3.382 Thread 0x25276800 nmethod 388 0x02c80a88 code [0x02c80bb0, 0x02c80cf8]
    Event: 3.382 Thread 0x25276800  389   !         org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager::findLocalClass (161 bytes)
    Event: 3.383 Thread 0x25276800 nmethod 389 0x02c80e48 code [0x02c80fb0, 0x02c81288]
    Event: 3.383 Thread 0x25276800  390             org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.FilterImpl::compare_ObjectArray (45 bytes)
    Event: 3.383 Thread 0x25276800 nmethod 390 0x02c81608 code [0x02c81710, 0x02c8181c]

    GC Heap History (4 events):
    Event: 1.788 GC heap before
    {Heap before GC invocations=0 (full 0):
     def new generation   total 12288K, used 10944K [0x04c00000, 0x05950000, 0x0f6a0000)
      eden space 10944K, 100% used [0x04c00000, 0x056b0000, 0x056b0000)
      from space 1344K,   0% used [0x056b0000, 0x056b0000, 0x05800000)
      to   space 1344K,   0% used [0x05800000, 0x05800000, 0x05950000)
     tenured generation   total 27328K, used 0K [0x0f6a0000, 0x11150000, 0x24c00000)
       the space 27328K,   0% used [0x0f6a0000, 0x0f6a0000, 0x0f6a0200, 0x11150000)
     Metaspace       used 3622K, capacity 3668K, committed 3776K, reserved 4480K
    Event: 1.793 GC heap after
    Heap after GC invocations=1 (full 0):
     def new generation   total 12288K, used 1344K [0x04c00000, 0x05950000, 0x0f6a0000)
      eden space 10944K,   0% used [0x04c00000, 0x04c00000, 0x056b0000)
      from space 1344K, 100% used [0x05800000, 0x05950000, 0x05950000)
      to   space 1344K,   0% used [0x056b0000, 0x056b0000, 0x05800000)
     tenured generation   total 27328K, used 1165K [0x0f6a0000, 0x11150000, 0x24c00000)
       the space 27328K,   4% used [0x0f6a0000, 0x0f7c3420, 0x0f7c3600, 0x11150000)
     Metaspace       used 3622K, capacity 3668K, committed 3776K, reserved 4480K
    }
    Event: 2.847 GC heap before
    {Heap before GC invocations=1 (full 0):
     def new generation   total 12288K, used 12288K [0x04c00000, 0x05950000, 0x0f6a0000)
      eden space 10944K, 100% used [0x04c00000, 0x056b0000, 0x056b0000)
      from space 1344K, 100% used [0x05800000, 0x05950000, 0x05950000)
      to   space 1344K,   0% used [0x056b0000, 0x056b0000, 0x05800000)
     tenured generation   total 27328K, used 1165K [0x0f6a0000, 0x11150000, 0x24c00000)
       the space 27328K,   4% used [0x0f6a0000, 0x0f7c3420, 0x0f7c3600, 0x11150000)
     Metaspace       used 5003K, capacity 5054K, committed 5120K, reserved 5504K
    Event: 2.854 GC heap after
    Heap after GC invocations=2 (full 0):
     def new generation   total 12288K, used 1344K [0x04c00000, 0x05950000, 0x0f6a0000)
      eden space 10944K,   0% used [0x04c00000, 0x04c00000, 0x056b0000)
      from space 1344K, 100% used [0x056b0000, 0x05800000, 0x05800000)
      to   space 1344K,   0% used [0x05800000, 0x05800000, 0x05950000)
     tenured generation   total 27328K, used 3927K [0x0f6a0000, 0x11150000, 0x24c00000)
       the space 27328K,  14% used [0x0f6a0000, 0x0fa75df0, 0x0fa75e00, 0x11150000)
     Metaspace       used 5003K, capacity 5054K, committed 5120K, reserved 5504K
    }

    Deoptimization events (0 events):
    No events

    Internal exceptions (10 events):
    Event: 0.510 Thread 0x029ac000 Exception <a 'java/lang/NoSuchMethodError': Method sun.misc.Unsafe.prefetchRead(Ljava/lang/Object;J)V name or signature does not match> (0x04c10c28) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-i586-cygwin\jdk8u65\4987\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp, lÁŢ.0B‡ö?
    Event: 1.408 Thread 0x029ac000 Exception <a 'java/lang/ClassNotFoundException': sun/net/www/protocol/e/Handler> (0x04e3e8b0) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-i586-cygwin\jdk8u65\4987\hotspot\src\share\vm\classfile\systemDictionary.cpp, line 210]
    Event: 1.539 Thread 0x029ac000 Exception <a 'java/lang/ClassNotFoundException': sun/net/www/protocol/c/Handler> (0x05137d30) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-i586-cygwin\jdk8u65\4987\hotspot\src\share\vm\classfile\systemDictionary.cpp, line 210]
    Event: 1.539 Thread 0x029ac000 Exception <a 'java/lang/ClassNotFoundException': sun/net/www/protocol/e/Handler> (0x051391b8) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-i586-cygwin\jdk8u65\4987\hotspot\src\share\vm\classfile\systemDictionary.cpp, line 210]
    Event: 1.546 Thread 0x029ac000 Exception <a 'java/lang/ClassNotFoundException': sun/net/www/protocol/e/Handler> (0x0513d508) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-i586-cygwin\jdk8u65\4987\hotspot\src\share\vm\classfile\systemDictionary.cpp, line 210]
    Event: 1.617 Thread 0x029ac000 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x051ca638) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-i586-cygwin\jdk8u65\4987\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1386]
    Event: 1.617 Thread 0x029ac000 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x051ca838) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-i586-cygwin\jdk8u65\4987\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1386]
    Event: 1.619 Thread 0x029ac000 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x051cdc58) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-i586-cygwin\jdk8u65\4987\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1386]
    Event: 1.619 Thread 0x029ac000 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x051cde58) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-i586-cygwin\jdk8u65\4987\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1386]
    Event: 3.338 Thread 0x2602c000 Exception <a 'java/io/FileNotFoundException'> (0x052058c8) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-i586-cygwin\jdk8u65\4987\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp, line 709]

    Events (10 events):
    Event: 3.506 loading class com/sun/org/apache/xerces/internal/impl/XMLDocumentScannerImpl
    Event: 3.508 loading class com/sun/org/apache/xerces/internal/impl/XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl
    Event: 3.510 loading class com/sun/org/apache/xerces/internal/xni/parser/XMLDocumentScanner
    Event: 3.510 loading class com/sun/org/apache/xerces/internal/xni/parser/XMLDocumentSource
    Event: 3.511 loading class com/sun/org/apache/xerces/internal/xni/parser/XMLDocumentSource done
    Event: 3.511 loading class com/sun/org/apache/xerces/internal/xni/parser/XMLDocumentScanner done
    Event: 3.511 loading class com/sun/org/apache/xerces/internal/impl/XMLEntityHandler
    Event: 3.511 loading class com/sun/org/apache/xerces/internal/impl/XMLEntityHandler done
    Event: 3.511 loading class com/sun/xml/internal/stream/XMLBufferListener
    Event: 3.511 loading class com/sun/xml/internal/stream/XMLBufferListener done


    Dynamic libraries:
    0x00400000 - 0x0044e000     E:\Programs_Portable\EclipsePortable\App\Eclipse\eclipse.exe
    0x77270000 - 0x773f0000     C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll
    0x76b70000 - 0x76c80000     C:\Windows\syswow64\kernel32.dll
    0x75770000 - 0x757b7000     C:\Windows\syswow64\KERNELBASE.dll
    0x76cc0000 - 0x76dc0000     C:\Windows\syswow64\USER32.dll
    0x758c0000 - 0x75950000     C:\Windows\syswow64\GDI32.dll
    0x750e0000 - 0x750ea000     C:\Windows\syswow64\LPK.dll
    0x75820000 - 0x758bd000     C:\Windows\syswow64\USP10.dll
    0x756c0000 - 0x7576c000     C:\Windows\syswow64\msvcrt.dll
    0x75110000 - 0x751b0000     C:\Windows\syswow64\ADVAPI32.dll
    0x75a40000 - 0x75a59000     C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll
    0x75950000 - 0x75a40000     C:\Windows\syswow64\RPCRT4.dll
    0x74d80000 - 0x74de0000     C:\Windows\syswow64\SspiCli.dll
    0x74d70000 - 0x74d7c000     C:\Windows\syswow64\CRYPTBASE.dll
    0x71fa0000 - 0x7213e000     C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.7601.17514_none_41e6975e2bd6f2b2\COMCTL32.dll
    0x76ae0000 - 0x76b37000     C:\Windows\syswow64\SHLWAPI.dll
    0x74de0000 - 0x74e40000     C:\Windows\system32\IMM32.DLL
    0x755f0000 - 0x756bc000     C:\Windows\syswow64\MSCTF.dll
    0x00230000 - 0x0023d000     E:\Programs_Portable\EclipsePortable\App\Eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.200.v20120913-144807\eclipse_1503.dll
    0x73260000 - 0x73269000     C:\Windows\system32\VERSION.dll
    0x6de70000 - 0x6def0000     C:\Windows\system32\uxtheme.dll
    0x76970000 - 0x76acc000     C:\Windows\system32\ole32.dll
    0x675a0000 - 0x67964000     E:\Programs_Portable\EclipsePortable\App\Eclipse\jre\bin\client\jvm.dll
    0x73480000 - 0x73487000     C:\Windows\system32\WSOCK32.dll
    0x76c80000 - 0x76cb5000     C:\Windows\syswow64\WS2_32.dll
    0x76810000 - 0x76816000     C:\Windows\syswow64\NSI.dll
    0x6dcb0000 - 0x6dce2000     C:\Windows\system32\WINMM.dll
    0x75bb0000 - 0x75bb5000     C:\Windows\syswow64\PSAPI.DLL
    0x702d0000 - 0x7038f000     C:\Windows\system32\MSVCR100.dll
    0x67590000 - 0x6759c000     E:\Programs_Portable\EclipsePortable\App\Eclipse\jre\bin\verify.dll
    0x67560000 - 0x67581000     E:\Programs_Portable\EclipsePortable\App\Eclipse\jre\bin\java.dll
    0x67540000 - 0x67553000     E:\Programs_Portable\EclipsePortable\App\Eclipse\jre\bin\zip.dll
    0x75bc0000 - 0x7680b000     C:\Windows\syswow64\SHELL32.dll
    0x73120000 - 0x7312b000     C:\Windows\system32\profapi.dll
    0x72eb0000 - 0x72ec7000     C:\Windows\system32\CRYPTSP.dll
    0x72e70000 - 0x72eab000     C:\Windows\system32\rsaenh.dll
    0x72860000 - 0x72877000     C:\Windows\system32\USERENV.dll
    0x67520000 - 0x67536000     E:\Programs_Portable\EclipsePortable\App\Eclipse\jre\bin\net.dll
    0x71e00000 - 0x71e3c000     C:\Windows\system32\mswsock.dll
    0x71de0000 - 0x71de6000     C:\Windows\System32\wship6.dll
    0x732a0000 - 0x732bc000     C:\Windows\system32\IPHLPAPI.DLL
    0x73290000 - 0x73297000     C:\Windows\system32\WINNSI.DLL
    0x71e50000 - 0x71e5d000     C:\Windows\system32\dhcpcsvc6.DLL
    0x71d40000 - 0x71d52000     C:\Windows\system32\dhcpcsvc.DLL
    0x67510000 - 0x6751f000     E:\Programs_Portable\EclipsePortable\App\Eclipse\jre\bin\nio.dll
    0x71da0000 - 0x71db0000     C:\Windows\system32\NLAapi.dll
    0x711d0000 - 0x711e0000     C:\Windows\system32\napinsp.dll
    0x711b0000 - 0x711c2000     C:\Windows\system32\pnrpnsp.dll
    0x732e0000 - 0x73324000     C:\Windows\system32\DNSAPI.dll
    0x711a0000 - 0x711a8000     C:\Windows\System32\winrnr.dll
    0x71d90000 - 0x71d95000     C:\Windows\System32\wshtcpip.dll
    0x71c90000 - 0x71c96000     C:\Windows\system32\rasadhlp.dll
    0x72380000 - 0x723b8000     C:\Windows\System32\fwpuclnt.dll
    0x67420000 - 0x6750b000     C:\Windows\system32\dbghelp.dll

    VM Arguments:
    jvm_args: -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5 -Dhelp.lucene.tokenizer=standard -Xms40m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m 
    java_command: <unknown>
    java_class_path (initial): E:\Programs_Portable\EclipsePortable\App\Eclipse\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
    Launcher Type: generic

    Environment Variables:
    PATH=E:/Programs_Portable/EclipsePortable/App/Eclipse/jre/bin/client;E:/Programs_Portable/EclipsePortable/App/Eclipse/jre/bin;E:/Programs_Portable/EclipsePortable/App/Eclipse/jre/lib/i386;E:\Programs_Portable\CommonFiles\MinGW\bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\TortoiseHg\;C:\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;E:\Programs_Portable\Dev-Cpp\minGW32\bin;E:\Programs_Portable\EclipsePortable;
    USERNAME=Admin
    OS=Windows_NT
    PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=AMD64 Family 16 Model 4 Stepping 3, AuthenticAMD



    ---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

    OS: Windows 7 , 64 bit Build 7601 (6.1.7601.18798)

    CPU:total 4 (4 cores per cpu, 1 threads per core) family 16 model 4 stepping 3, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, popcnt, mmxext, 3dnowpref, lzcnt, sse4a, tsc, tscinvbit, tscinv

    Memory: 4k page, physical 7567052k(6066964k free), swap 15132252k(13562444k free)

    vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (25.65-b01) for windows-x86 JRE (1.8.0_65-b17), built on Oct  6 2015 17:26:22 by "java_re" with MS VC++ 10.0 (VS2010)

    time: Fri Oct 28 11:19:26 2016
    elapsed time: 3 seconds (0d 0h 0m 3s)
```

Comment: (Re)install latest Java for your platform.

Comment: It solved the problem. Much thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen mentioned, reinstalling java solved the problem